# Python: Check if a specific line of text is in a file

Tags: python

I want to have a Python program that will read through a text file, then print whether or not a specific string of text was found in that file.

Here is the code that I can't get working:

```
f=open("to-read.txt","r")

found = False
for x in f.readlines():
    print(x)
    if x is "Hello, World!" or x is "Hello, World!\n":
        found = True

print(found)
```

I want the code to print `True` if Hello, World is on any of the lines in `to-read.txt`, and `False` if not.

When I run it, it reads the lines but never finds "Hello, World!".

Comment: Use `==` for string comparison, not `is` (that does reference comparison)

Comment: (and of course, you don't need a `for` loop: `print("Hello, World!\n" in f.readlines())` will do just fine)

Comment: Searching for just `"Hello, World!"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("to-read.txt", "r") as f:
   found = any("Hello, World!" in x for x in f)

print(found)
```

or, if you want to make sure the line *is exactly* "Hello, World!" rather than *contains* it, you can use `==`.

```
    found = any(x == "Hello, World!\n" for x in f)
```

or even just

```
    found = "Hello, World!\n" in f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **in** keyword to check if the specific string exists in your file

```
with open('to-read.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in f.readlines]    # Getting each line without the new_line '\n'

    if 'Hello, World!' in lines:
        print(True)

    else:
         print(False)
```